# Creating a user gives it admin permissions everywhere

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a user that only has read / write permissions for a specific database, but when logging in as the new user, it has permissions to create users, modify everything, etc.

```
> use testdb
< 'switched to db testdb'

> db.createUser({
  user: 'testuser',
  pwd: 'totallysecurepassword',
  roles: [{
    role: 'readWrite', db: 'testdb'
  }]
})
< { ok: 1 }

> db.getUser('testuser')
< {
  _id: 'testdb.testuser',
  userId: UUID("1896349f-c17c-4755-9918-ea9977b98331"),
  user: 'testuser',
  db: 'testdb',
  roles: [ { role: 'readWrite', db: 'testdb' } ],
  mechanisms: [ 'SCRAM-SHA-1', 'SCRAM-SHA-256' ]
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, and I'm 100% sure I'm logging in as the correct user.

Comment: how your mongod.conf file looks like? Do you have security active?

Comment: I have `security:
  authorization: "enabled"` in my mongod.conf

Comment: authentication / authorisation  is working even when you add only at least security:-> keyFile: /theKeyFileFolder/theKeyFIle unless it is different authentication ... , attempted your steps in 4.2 and they are fine ... , so the only issue seems in config...

Comment: "authorization" is the only key I have in the security part, is that an issue? If it is, what do I add / change to fix it?

Comment: comment authorization and just add security: -> keyFile: /xxxx/xxx etc. and this will be completely enought ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel dumb, I forgot to add the `--auth` flag